# Facebook privacy sets to Only Me

Tags: ios, facebook, privacy

We released an iOS app with a corresponding facebook app, which at the time had Default Activity Privacy set to "None (User Default)"

At the time, posting things would result in, for example, posts to friends, or friends of friends, etc, depending on the users' default

Since then, we've released another version of the ios app, and changed the default activity privacy on facebook to public. it seems now every user that interacted in some way with the facebook app (not even posting or granting permission, even the ones who declined giving permission) has his privacy set to Only Me
New users who sign up for the first time have their privacy set to public, as intended. But all the users who previously used the app are 'lost' as their posts won't be seen by anyone. Does anyone know the cause of this, and/or a way to fix it?